# realm browser can change columns schema?

Tags: swift, realm

I use realm browser (version 2.0)

I imported csv files to realm file

csv file have many columns and many types (String , Float , Int)

but I open realmfiles all columns are made String type

Can I change columns schema?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not at this time. This is a limitation of Realm itself in that it's not possible to change the schema of a Realm file without performing a migration. That being said, it's on the roadmap!

If you want to specifically control the schema of a Realm file, at the moment it would be easier if you wrote a small helper utility to generate the Realm file for you. This would allow the maximum amount of control.